# how to get the value of $_GET['value'] in js in an attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

Sorry I am not sure how to explain this in a short way and put it as the title.
Anyways, I have an `href` attribute for example

```
<a href="done-ajax.php?as=done&item=113">Done</a>
```

I want to use jquery to get the number 113 is this possible and save it into a variable?
Because in my done-ajax.php I am checking

```
if (isset($_GET['as'], $_GET['item'])){}
```

Also, I am saving the 113 in jquery for further use too.
Sorry if my explanation is really bad.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: ah thx thx, so regex is the only way to do this?

Comment: I was stupid >"< I could have used the split and split the = then get the array